# Correlation Heatmap is not showing

Tags: python, visualization, heatmap, correlation

My correlation heatmap aren't showing and I have no clue why. My datasets includes multiple categorical values that I have to convert into numerical datas using Label Encoder and One Hot Encoder

```
correlation_matrix = df2.corr()
print(correlation_matrix)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
heatmap = sns.heatmap(correlation_matrix, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

[This is shown everytime I try to run the heatmap code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKANS.png)

I've tried multiple different ways to generate a heatmap but it either shows the same result or no result at all.